# Ejecutar un código cuando el "i" de un for está en un número determinado python 3.7.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7, anaconda

Yo quiero hacer un programa que cada diez veces me ponga:

```
print("hola!")
```

Pero mi forma es muy poco práctica.
Esta es mi forma:

```
for i in range(30):
    if i == 10:
        print("hola!")
    elif i == 20:
        print("hola!")
    elif i == 30:
        print("hola!")
    else:
        print(i)
        continue
```

Por lo que veo hay muchos `if` (if cada vez que i sea múltiplo de 10)

¿Hay alguna forma más rápida de hacer esto?

Comment: tienes que buscar que "i" sea multiplo de 10, ejemplo `if(i % 10 == 0)`

Comment: se usa los parentesis en un if (se que funciona) porque es como muy de otro lenguaje

Comment: si, se me paso, pero funcionan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es simplemente hacer que lo pinte cuando sea múltiplo de 10:

```
for i in range(30):
    if i%10==0:
      print("hola")
    else:
      print(i)
```

Comment: como detalle, faltaria el caso else, para imprimir el numero

Comment: Totalmente Jakala, se me pasó. Gracias!

Comment: como no lo pense, :face_palm: